# How to Auto-resize font size to fit text box height / width?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am trying to have text automatically size its font to fill an entire text component.

My current approach is to set font size as a function of the number of text characters and the text components height and width but I can't find the right coefficients to make this work nicely.

Is there a simpler or more elegant way?

Does truncateToFit work on Text? I read somewhere that it doesn't work well.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that I would like it to scale beyond the max font size (which is 127 i believe).  How is this done?  scaleX?

Answer (score 22):

AS3 sample function. You should call it anytime your TextField's content changes

```
function Autosize(txt:TextField):void 
{
  //You set this according to your TextField's dimensions
  var maxTextWidth:int = 145; 
  var maxTextHeight:int = 30; 

  var f:TextFormat = txt.getTextFormat();

  //decrease font size until the text fits  
  while (txt.textWidth > maxTextWidth || txt.textHeight > maxTextHeight) {
    f.size = int(f.size) - 1;
    txt.setTextFormat(f);
  }

}
```

Comment: I voted up, thanks for the tip. Do you know how to scale beyond 145?

Comment: Sorry, I don't how to scale the font size beyond 145

Comment: When doing goal-seeking in a UI toolkit like this, you might want to put in a safeguard in so that if your changes in the input value aren't actually affecting the output value (say due to a change in toolkit behaviour in some situation), you catch it and give up, to avoid an infinite loop.

Comment: 'txt.setTextFormat' does NOT change the 'txt.textHeight' when scale down. What is the solution?

Comment: For the sake of confusion, please camelCase your function name, and maybe change it?